# Kafka and pyspark program: Unable to determine why dataframe is empty

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming, spark-kafka-integration

Below is my first program working with kafka and pyspark. The code seems to run without exceptions, but the output of my query is empty.

I am initiating spark and kafka. Later, in Kafka initiation, I subscribed the topic = "quickstart-events" and from terminal produced messages for this topic. But when I run this code, it gives me blank dataframes.

How do I resolve?

Code:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext, SparkSession, DataFrame
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, ArrayType, StructField, IntegerType, StringType, DoubleType

spark = SparkSession.builder \
.appName("Spark-Kafka-Integration") \
.master("local[2]") \
.getOrCreate()

dsraw = spark.readStream \
.format("kafka") \
.option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "kafka:9092") \
.option("subscribe", "quickstart-events") \
.load()

ds = dsraw.selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)")
print(type(ds))

rawQuery = dsraw \
        .writeStream \
        .queryName("query1")\
        .format("memory")\
        .start()

raw = spark.sql("select * from query1")
raw.show() # empty output

rawQuery = ds \
        .writeStream \
        .queryName("query2")\
        .format("memory")\
        .start()

raw = spark.sql("select * from query2")
raw.show()  # empty output
print("complete")
```

Output:

```
+---+-----+-----+---------+------+---------+-------------+
|key|value|topic|partition|offset|timestamp|timestampType|
+---+-----+-----+---------+------+---------+-------------+
+---+-----+-----+---------+------+---------+-------------+

+---+-----+
|key|value|
+---+-----+
+---+-----+
```

Comment: Why do you need to writeStream or two sql queries? You can `ds.show()`. Besides, is there actually data _actively written_ to your topic EU) while you are running the Spark code? Note that you didn't provide the startingOffsets option

Answer (score 1):

if you are learning and experimenting with kafka spark streaming then it is fine.

just use:

```
    while (True):
    time.sleep(5)
    print("queryresult")
    raw.show()  # it will start printing the result
```

instead of

```
            raw.show() # it will run only once that's why not printig the result.
```

**DO NOT USE for Production code.**

Better to write like:

```
spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("Spark-Kafka-Integration") \
    .master("local[2]") \
    .getOrCreate()


dsraw = spark \
    .readStream \
    .format("kafka") \
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "kafka:9092") \
    .option("subscribe", "quickstart-events") \
    .load()

ds = dsraw.selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)")

rawQuery = \
    ds \
    .writeStream \
    .format("console") \
    .outputMode("append") \
    .start()

rawQuery.awaitTermination()
```

it will automatically print the result on the console.